# Full screen notification for Android14. Push notification skips, but I want the intent to open automatical without having to click on the notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-fullscreen, android-14

The push notification jumps correctly, I have followed the steps in the Android 14 documentation to create full screen intents but only the notification is created and it is necessary to click on it for the intent to open full screen, this did not happen in previous versions , I need it to open automatically

This is the code to create the notification:

```
PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,                                                                              intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            } else {
                fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                        intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            }
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID2)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle(title)
                            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM) // CATEGORY_CALL
                            .setGroup(GROUP_KEY)
                            .setGroupSummary(true)
                            .setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);
```

Comment: If your screen is on, that is the expected behavior. Does your full screen intent open if your screen is off?

Comment: yes, my full screen intent opens correctly if the screen is off. But I want it to be the same with the screen on, without push notification, I need that the intent open without push notification, before Android14 it was possible, but with Android14 I can not fix

Comment: That's not possible, sorry.

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake, do you know why?